# How to use Dialogflow Phone gateway and handling it in backend platform like nodejs

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm trying to understand phone gateway implementation in dialogflow but dont see much of documentation for how to handle in backend code using nodejs or any third party apps like twilio,viber etc.
My doubt is whether is it available for now or not and is their any documents regarding phone gateway which can be done through google mini device for voice calling?

Please correct me if I'm wrong about what I understand.

Comment: There's a Dialogflow sample available for Telephony in Node.js: https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-telephony-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Dialogflow phone gateway is a great feature provided by Dialogflow. It is simple to activate. Just follow the instructions in the **Integrations** tab.

All your intents and webhook will just work fine as they do in the bot. But the response type is little different from other platforms. So check that once before building responses.

It only supports speech response that is returned to the user in the phone call.

Answer (score 0):

as per Google documentation, it uses the V2Beta1 version of the API. It means you have all the normal fields of the V2 API inside the body and parameters of the webhook call (+1 "MlEnabled" field, but not important for the telefony gateway). See more here https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v2-beta-v2-migration-guide-api . I have also been searching for extra fields like the phone number who is calling (to use it in backend tasks like CRM lookup), but this is not there yet (I analysed the JSON response, there is nothing so far).

Some tip to integrate with Twilio (my use case too) : you can perfectly route the twilio call to a simple Twilio callflow (like checking for opening hours) then to the incoming DialogFlow number (as you would do with the black number of an IVR provider) and transfer the Dialogflow call to another incoming phone numbers (controlled by Twilio) where you do the rest of the callflow (typically the skill based routing).

Example : after the call, Twilio checks for opening hours > OK  > forward to Dialogflow phone nbr for intent recognition > identify intent nbr1 > route to phone nbr1 of Twilio which is connected to a routing/queue to agent group nbr1 (idem for intents nbr2, 3, 4 ...).
In this example, some useful fields are missing in the JSON like the phone nbr of the caller(CLI), the phone number dialed, eventually some UUI ISDN field, ... that you would like to use for a CRM lookup and CTI popup. Let's keep an eye on it and maybe Google will add it in V2beta2 ...?

Comment: Is it possible to detect what number user is calling from?